# Правильно ли составлены предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

*В своей рукописи "Чернобыль. Как это было" Дятлов А. С. пытается оправдать действия оперативного персонала станции, а вместе с этим и себя. Но, оправдываются виновные.*

Comment: После "но" запятую уберите, она там лишняя.

Comment: Пафос понятен, но зачем инициалы стоят позади фамилии? Или это строки из приговора?